# How does HttpApplication work in .net HttpRuntime?

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpapplication

Not sure whether HttpApplication works as a session mechanism.
Once HttpApplication was created by HttpApplicationFactory via my first request, would HttpApplication be reused by HttpApplicationFactory via my second request? or renewed?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> One instance of the HttpApplication class is used to process many
>   requests in its lifetime. However, it can process only one request at
>   a time. Thus, member variables can be used to store per-request data.

So the application object might have a long lifetime, but for different requests, different instances of the HttpApplication might be used. 
This also implies that HttpApplication cannot be used as a Session mechanism. As I understand it, there are no reliable rules when the instances are reused - an instance can be reused for another user's request.
If you need Session memory, there is the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. If you need a Cache that is pertained across requests (and users), there is the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that also allows to add rules on when cached items are removed.